# MySQL query returning data but Database PHP returns array()

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a query that when executed in MySQL returns 18 records, but when i run the php code it returns an empty array:

PHP code:

```
$db = &JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery($query);
$list = $db->loadObjectList();
die (var_dump($list));
```

query var_dump:

```
string(1215) " SELECT i.title AS title, i.metadesc, i.metakey, c.name as section, i.image_caption, i.image_credits, i.video_caption, i.video_credits, i.extra_fields_search, i.created, CONCAT(i.introtext, i.fulltext) AS text, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(i.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', i.id, i.alias) ELSE i.id END as slug, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as catslug FROM #__catalog_items AS i INNER JOIN #__catalog_categories AS c ON c.id=i.catid AND c.access IN(1,1) WHERE (MATCH(i.title, i.introtext, i.`fulltext`,i.extra_fields_search,i.image_caption,i.image_credits,i.video_caption,i.video_credits,i.metadesc,i.metakey) AGAINST ('+×ž×œ×š* +×”×™×¢×¨*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) AND i.trash = 0 AND i.published = 1 AND i.access IN(1,1) AND c.published = 1 AND c.access IN(1,1) AND c.trash = 0 AND ( i.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR i.publish_up <= '2012-11-21 16:20:36' ) AND ( i.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR i.publish_down >= '2012-11-21 16:20:36' ) AND c.language IN ('he-IL', '*') AND i.language IN ('he-IL', '*') GROUP BY i.id ORDER BY i.created DESC"
```

Weird codes '+×ž×œ×š* +×”×™×¢×¨*' is due the site is in hebrew, i do not know if it has something to do, because as i explained, when executing the query through phpmyadmin it works as expected.

Any idea?

**Edit**

$db var_dump:

```
object(JFalangDatabase)#155 (26) {
["_mlTableList"]=> array(14) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "catalog_categories"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "categories"
    [3]=>
    string(15) "contact_details"
    [4]=>
    string(7) "content"
    [5]=>
    string(13) "faq_questions"
    [6]=>
    string(4) "menu"
    [7]=>
    string(7) "modules"
    [8]=>
    string(18) "recipes_categories"
    [9]=>
    string(20) "recipes_extra_fields"
    [10]=>
    string(13) "recipes_items"
    [11]=>
    string(20) "recipes_servingtypes"
    [12]=>
    string(12) "recipes_tags"
    [13]=>
    string(13) "recipes_units"
}
["_refTables"]=>
    array(6) {
    ["fieldTablePairs"]=>
    array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "catalog_categories"
}
["tableAliases"]=>
    array(2) {
    ["catalog_items"]=>
  string(1) "i"
  ["catalog_categories"]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
["reverseTableAliases"]=>
array(2) {
  ["i"]=>
  string(13) "catalog_items"
  ["c"]=>
  string(18) "catalog_categories"
}
["fieldAliases"]=>
array(10) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(5) "title"
  ["metadesc"]=>
  string(8) "metadesc"
  ["metakey"]=>
  string(7) "metakey"
  ["section"]=>
  string(4) "name"
  ["image_caption"]=>
  string(13) "image_caption"
  ["image_credits"]=>
  string(13) "image_credits"
  ["video_caption"]=>
  string(13) "video_caption"
  ["video_credits"]=>
  string(13) "video_credits"
  ["extra_fields_search"]=>
  string(19) "extra_fields_search"
  ["created"]=>
  string(7) "created"
}
["fieldTableAliasData"]=>
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fieldNameAlias"]=>
    string(5) "title"
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(5) "title"
    ["tableNameAlias"]=>
    string(1) "i"
    ["tableName"]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fieldNameAlias"]=>
    string(8) "metadesc"
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(8) "metadesc"
    ["tableNameAlias"]=>
    string(1) "i"
    ["tableName"]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fieldNameAlias"]=>
    string(7) "metakey"
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(7) "metakey"
    ["tableNameAlias"]=>
    string(1) "i"
    ["tableName"]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fieldNameAlias"]=>
    string(7) "section"
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["tableNameAlias"]=>
    string(1) "c"
    ["tableName"]=>
    string(18) "catalog_categories"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fieldNameAlias"]=>
    string(13) "image_caption"
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(13) "image_caption"
    ["tableNameAlias"]=>
    string(1) "i"
    ["tableName"]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fieldNameAlias"]=>
    string(13) "image_credits"
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(13) "image_credits"
    ["tableNameAlias"]=>
    string(1) "i"
    ["tableName"]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fieldNameAlias"]=>
    string(13) "video_caption"
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(13) "video_caption"
    ["tableNameAlias"]=>
    string(1) "i"
    ["tableName"]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fieldNameAlias"]=>
    string(13) "video_credits"
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(13) "video_credits"
    ["tableNameAlias"]=>
    string(1) "i"
    ["tableName"]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fieldNameAlias"]=>
    string(19) "extra_fields_search"
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(19) "extra_fields_search"
    ["tableNameAlias"]=>
    string(1) "i"
    ["tableName"]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(4) {
    ["fieldNameAlias"]=>
    string(7) "created"
    ["fieldName"]=>
    string(7) "created"
    ["tableNameAlias"]=>
    string(1) "i"
    ["tableName"]=>
    string(13) "catalog_items"
  }
}
["fieldCount"]=>
int(13)
}
["_skipSetRefTables"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["orig_limit"]=>
    int(0)
    ["orig_offset"]=>
    int(0)
    ["_table_prefix"]=>
    string(6) "oyhkl_"
    ["profileData"]=>
    array(2) {
    ["JOverrideDatabase::setRefTables"]=>
    array(3) {
    ["total"]=>
  float(0.0053415298461914)
  ["count"]=>
  int(20)
  ["start"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
["JFalangDatabase::loadObjectList"]=>
array(3) {
  ["total"]=>
  float(0.011144638061523)
  ["count"]=>
  int(7)
  ["start"]=>
  array(0) {
       }
    }
}
["name"]=>
string(6) "mysqli"
["nameQuote":protected]=>
string(1) "`"
["nullDate":protected]=>
string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
["dbMinimum":protected]=>
string(5) "5.0.4"
["_database":"JDatabase":private]=>
string(20) "jom_database"
["connection":protected]=>
object(mysqli)#156 (17) {
    ["affected_rows"]=>
    int(0)
    ["client_info"]=>
    string(6) "5.1.49"
    ["client_version"]=>
    int(50149)
    ["connect_errno"]=>
    int(0)
    ["connect_error"]=>
    NULL
    ["errno"]=>
    int(0)
    ["error"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["field_count"]=>
    int(13)
    ["host_info"]=>
    string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket"
    ["info"]=>
    NULL
    ["insert_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["server_info"]=>
    string(17) "5.1.63-0+squeeze1"
    ["server_version"]=>
    int(50163)
    ["sqlstate"]=>
    string(5) "00000"
    ["protocol_version"]=>
    int(10)
    ["thread_id"]=>
    int(94278)
    ["warning_count"]=>
    int(0)
}
["count":protected]=>
    int(20)
    ["cursor":protected]=>

Warning: var_dump(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in    /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/plugins/search/catalog/catalog.php on line 198

Warning: var_dump(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/plugins/search/catalog/catalog.php on line 198

Warning: var_dump(): Property access is not allowed yet in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/plugins/search/catalog/catalog.php on line 198

Warning: var_dump(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/plugins/search/catalog/catalog.php on line 198

Warning: var_dump(): Property access is not allowed yet in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/plugins/search/catalog/catalog.php on line 198

object(mysqli_result)#317 (5) {
    ["current_field"]=>
    NULL
    ["field_count"]=>
    NULL
    ["lengths"]=>
    NULL
    ["num_rows"]=>
    NULL
   ["type"]=>
    NULL
}
["debug":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["limit":protected]=>
    int(50)
    ["log":protected]=>
    array(20) {
    [0]=>
    string(142) "SELECT extension_id AS id, element AS "option", params, enabled
    FROM oyhkl_extensions
    WHERE `type` = 'component' AND `element` = 'com_catalog'"
    [1]=>
    string(142) "SELECT extension_id AS id, element AS "option", params, enabled
    FROM oyhkl_extensions
    WHERE `type` = 'component' AND `element` = 'com_recipes'"
    [2]=>
    string(389) "SELECT m.id, m.menutype, m.title, m.alias, m.note, m.path AS route, m.link, m.type, m.level, m.language,m.browserNav, m.access, m.params, m.home, m.img, m.template_style_id, m.component_id, m.parent_id,e.element as component
    FROM oyhkl_menu AS m
    LEFT JOIN oyhkl_extensions AS e ON m.component_id = e.extension_id
    WHERE m.published = 1 AND m.parent_id > 0 AND m.client_id = 0
    ORDER BY m.lft"
    [3]=>
    string(62) "SELECT joomlatablename,tablepkID FROM `oyhkl_falang_tableinfo`"
    [4]=>
    string(47) "SELECT * FROM oyhkl_languages ORDER BY ordering"
    [5]=>
    string(40) "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `oyhkl_languages`"
    [6]=>
    string(141) "SELECT extension_id AS id, element AS "option", params, enabled
    FROM oyhkl_extensions
    WHERE `type` = 'component' AND `element` = 'com_falang'"
    [7]=>
    string(395) "SELECT falang_content.reference_field, falang_content.value, falang_content.reference_id, falang_content.original_value 
    FROM oyhkl_falang_content AS falang_content
    WHERE falang_content.language_id=2
AND falang_content.published=1
    AND falang_content.reference_id IN(101,102,103,104,105,167,106,164,109,110,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,169)
    AND falang_content.reference_table='menu'"
    [8]=>
    string(141) "SELECT extension_id AS id, element AS "option", params, enabled
    FROM oyhkl_extensions
    WHERE `type` = 'component' AND `element` = 'com_search'"
    [9]=>
    string(213) "SELECT id, home, template, s.params
    FROM oyhkl_template_styles as s
    LEFT JOIN oyhkl_extensions as e ON e.element=s.template AND e.type='template' AND e.client_id=s.client_id
    WHERE s.client_id = 0 AND e.enabled = 1"
    [10]=>
    string(444) "SELECT a.title, a.description AS text, "" AS created, "2" AS browsernav, a.id AS catid,  CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END as slug
    FROM oyhkl_categories AS a
    WHERE (a.title LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.description LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%') AND a.published IN (1,2) AND a.extension = 'com_content'AND a.access IN (1,1) AND a.language in ('he-IL','*')
    GROUP BY a.id
    ORDER BY a.title DESC LIMIT 0, 50"
    [11]=>
    string(1049) "SELECT a.name AS title, '' AS created, a.con_position, a.misc,  CASE     WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END as slug, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as catslug, CONCAT_WS(',', a.name, a.con_position, a.misc) AS text,CONCAT_WS(' / ', '×× ×©×™ ×§×©×¨', c.title) AS section,'2' AS browsernav
    FROM oyhkl_contact_details AS a
    INNER JOIN oyhkl_categories AS c ON c.id = a.catid
    WHERE (a.name LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%'OR a.misc LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%'OR a.con_position LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%'OR a.address LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%'OR a.suburb LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%'OR a.state LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%'OR a.country LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%'OR a.postcode LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%'OR a.telephone LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%'OR a.fax LIKE '%×ž×œ×š ×”×™×¢×¨%') AND a.published IN (1,2) AND c.published=1 AND a.access IN (1,1) AND c.access IN (1,1) AND a.language in ('he-IL','*') AND c.language in ('he-IL','*')
    GROUP BY a.id, a.con_position, a.misc
    ORDER BY a.name DESC LIMIT 0, 50"
    [12]=>
    string(1178) "SELECT a.title AS title, a.metadesc, a.metakey, a.created AS created,CONCAT(a.introtext,a.fulltext) AS text,c.title AS section,  CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END as slug, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as catslug, '2' AS browsernav
    FROM oyhkl_content AS a
    INNER JOIN oyhkl_categories AS c ON c.id=a.catid
    WHERE ((a.title LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.introtext LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.fulltext LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.metakey LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.metadesc LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%') AND (a.title LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.introtext LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.fulltext LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.metakey LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.metadesc LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%'))AND a.state=1 AND c.published = 1 AND a.access IN (1,1) AND c.access IN (1,1) AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2012-11-21 17:01:20') AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2012-11-21 17:01:20') AND a.language in ('he-IL','*') AND c.language in ('he-IL','*')
    GROUP BY a.id, a.title, a.metadesc, a.metakey, a.created, a.introtext, a.fulltext, c.title, a.alias, c.alias, c.id
    ORDER BY a.created DESC LIMIT 0, 50"
    [13]=>
    string(998) "SELECT c.*, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as slug
    FROM oyhkl_categories as c
    LEFT JOIN oyhkl_categories AS s ON (s.lft < c.lft AND s.rgt > c.rgt AND c.language in ('he-IL','*')) OR (s.lft >= c.lft AND s.rgt <= c.rgt)
    LEFT JOIN  (SELECT cat.id as id FROM oyhkl_categories AS cat JOIN oyhkl_categories AS parent ON cat.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt WHERE parent.extension = 'com_content' AND parent.published != 1 GROUP BY cat.id) AS badcats ON badcats.id = c.id
    WHERE (c.extension='com_content' OR c.extension='system') AND c.access IN (1,1) AND c.published = 1 AND s.id=8 AND badcats.id is null
    GROUP BY c.id, c.asset_id, c.access, c.alias, c.checked_out, c.checked_out_time,
        c.created_time, c.created_user_id, c.description, c.extension, c.hits, c.language, c.level,
        c.lft, c.metadata, c.metadesc, c.metakey, c.modified_time, c.note, c.params, c.parent_id,
        c.path, c.published, c.rgt, c.title, c.modified_user_id
    ORDER BY c.lft"
    [14]=>
    string(325) "SELECT falang_content.reference_field, falang_content.value, falang_content.reference_id, falang_content.original_value 
    FROM oyhkl_falang_content AS falang_content
    WHERE falang_content.language_id=2
AND falang_content.published=1
   AND falang_content.reference_id IN(1,8)
   AND falang_content.reference_table='categories'"
    [15]=>
    string(142) "SELECT extension_id AS id, element AS "option", params, enabled
    FROM oyhkl_extensions
    WHERE `type` = 'component' AND `element` = 'com_content'"
    [16]=>
    string(1089) "SELECT a.title AS title, a.metadesc, a.metakey, a.created AS created,     CONCAT(a.introtext,a.fulltext) AS text, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END as slug, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as catslug, c.title AS section, '2' AS browsernav
    FROM oyhkl_content AS a
    INNER JOIN oyhkl_categories AS c ON c.id=a.catid AND c.access IN (1,1)
    WHERE ((a.title LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.introtext LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.fulltext LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.metakey LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.metadesc LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%') AND (a.title LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.introtext LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.fulltext LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.metakey LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.metadesc LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%')) AND a.state = 2 AND c.published = 1 AND a.access IN (1,1) AND c.access IN (1,1) AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2012-11-21 17:01:20') AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2012-11-21 17:01:20') AND a.language in ('he-IL','*') AND c.language in ('he-IL','*')
    ORDER BY a.created DESC LIMIT 0, 49"
    [17]=>
    string(670) "SELECT a.name AS title, "" AS created, a.link AS text,  CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END as slug, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as catslug,CONCAT_WS(' / ', '×ž×–×™×Ÿ ×—×“×©×•×ª', c.title) AS section,"1" AS browsernav
    FROM oyhkl_newsfeeds AS a
    INNER JOIN oyhkl_categories as c ON c.id = a.catid
    WHERE ((a.name LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.link LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%') AND (a.name LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.link LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%'))AND a.published IN (1,2) AND c.published = 1 AND c.access IN (1,1) AND a.language in ('he-IL','*') AND c.language in ('he-IL','*')
    ORDER BY a.name ASC LIMIT 0, 50"
    [18]=>
    string(775) "SELECT a.title AS title, a.description AS text, a.created AS created, a.url,  CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END as slug, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as catslug, CONCAT_WS(' / ', '×—×™×¤×•×© - ×§×™×©×•×¨×™ ×¨×©×ª', c.title) AS section, '1' AS browsernav
    FROM oyhkl_weblinks AS a
    INNER JOIN oyhkl_categories AS c ON c.id = a.catid
    WHERE ((a.url LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.description LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%' OR a.title LIKE '%×ž×œ×š%') AND (a.url LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.description LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%' OR a.title LIKE '%×”×™×¢×¨%')) AND a.state in (1,2) AND  c.published=1 AND  c.access IN (1,1) AND a.language in ('he-IL','*') AND c.language in ('he-IL','*')
    ORDER BY a.created DESC LIMIT 0, 50"
    [19]=>
    string(1230) "SELECT i.title AS title,
    i.metadesc,
    i.metakey,
    c.name as section,
    i.image_caption,
    i.image_credits,
    i.video_caption,
    i.video_credits,
    i.extra_fields_search,
    i.created,
    CONCAT(i.introtext, i.fulltext) AS text,
    CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(i.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', i.id, i.alias) ELSE i.id END as slug,
    CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as catslug
    FROM oyhkl_catalog_items AS i
    INNER JOIN oyhkl_catalog_categories AS c ON c.id=i.catid AND c.access  IN(1,1) 
    WHERE (MATCH(i.title, i.introtext, i.`fulltext`,i.extra_fields_search,i.image_caption,i.image_credits,i.video_caption,i.video_credits,i.metadesc,i.metakey) AGAINST ('+×ž×œ×š* +×”×™×¢×¨*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
    AND i.trash = 0
    AND i.published = 1
    AND i.access  IN(1,1) 
    AND c.published = 1
    AND c.access  IN(1,1) 
    AND c.trash = 0
    AND ( i.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR i.publish_up <= '2012-11-21 17:01:20' )
    AND ( i.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR i.publish_down >= '2012-11-21 17:01:20' ) AND c.language IN ('he-IL', '*') AND i.language IN ('he-IL', '*')  GROUP BY i.id     ORDER BY i.created DESC LIMIT 0, 50"
}
["offset":protected]=>
int(0)
["sql":protected]=>
string(1215) "
    SELECT i.title AS title,
    i.metadesc,
    i.metakey,
    c.name as section,
    i.image_caption,
    i.image_credits,
    i.video_caption,
    i.video_credits,
    i.extra_fields_search,
    i.created,
    CONCAT(i.introtext, i.fulltext) AS text,
    CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(i.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', i.id, i.alias) ELSE i.id END as slug,
    CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as catslug
    FROM #__catalog_items AS i
    INNER JOIN #__catalog_categories AS c ON c.id=i.catid AND c.access  IN(1,1)
```

Comment: what is the output of $query?

Comment: Also `echo $db->getErrorMsg();`

Comment: Can be something to do with encoding

Comment: cast query right after connection `set names utf8` (or else encoding you're using)

Comment: the output of $query is 18 row sets with the right data..

Comment: execute the query within a try catch block, so that you can read the exception message if thrown

Comment: var_dump of $db->getErrorMsg(); = string(0) ""

Comment: I tried the try catch but no Exception is raised..

Comment: I suspect where the error might come from, im using the CMS Joomla and the Falang plugin which is like Joomfish. This plugin overrides the database queries and might not be doing it correctly when hebrew characters.. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. The problem is that Falang (a joomla plugin) was modifying the database query including additional sql. I just fixed those queries and the problem got solved.